# How to read a file without updating the cursor?

Tags: python

I have a simple python file: `f = open('example.txt, 'r')`.

How do I read it without updating the cursor:

Example: `f contents '1234'`.

Given the following script:

```
print f.read(1)
print f.read(1)
```

it will print: `12`. How do I make it print `11`?

Comment: `f.seek(0)` followed by `f.read(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `f.seek(0)`.

Demo:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> s = StringIO('1234')
>>> s.read(1)
>>> '1'
>>> s.seek(0)
>>> 0
>>> s.read(1)
>>> '1'
```

> If I want to "reset" only certain reads, how can I do it?

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.

You can get the current position with `s.tell()`, so `s.seek(s.tell() - 1)`
"resets one `read(1)`", so to speak.

```
>>> s = StringIO('1234')
>>> s.read(1)
>>> '1'
>>> s.read(1)
>>> '2'
>>> s.read(1)
>>> '3'
>>> s.seek(s.tell() - 1)
>>> 2
>>> s.read(1)
>>> '3'
```

> I want a function read(file, count, modify_cursor=False)

```
>>> s = StringIO('abcdefghijk')
>>> 
>>> def read(file, count, modify_cursor=False):
...:    here = file.tell()
...:    content = file.read(count)
...:    if not modify_cursor:
...:        file.seek(here)
...:    return content
...:
>>> read(s, 3)
>>> 'abc'
>>> read(s, 3)
>>> 'abc'
>>> read(s, 3, modify_cursor=True)
>>> 'abc'
>>> read(s, 1)
>>> 'd'
>>> read(s, 1000)
>>> 'defghijk'
>>> read(s, 1)
>>> 'd'
```

Comment: Can you please implement a function that reads from a stream without changing its cursor? it's not an homework exercise, I just did it and it got some wierd bugs

Comment: @Billie I  don't know what you are asking. That's a new question right? I suggest that you open a new question, describe what you want in detail, and show the code that produces bugs.

Comment: It's the same question. I want a function read(file, count, modify_cursor=False) that give me `count` characters from the current cursor position, with an option to not modify the cursor

Comment: I would probably have written that `read` function to do `f.tell()` *first* rather than seeking backwards by `len(content)`. It might make a difference if you're in Python 3.x and using an encoding where string lengths may not correspond to byte counts. Also, I would avoid using `file` as an argument name because it's a built-in.

Comment: @DanielPryden thanks, I used your suggestion. `file` is not a builtin in Python 3 any more.

Comment: @Billie does the function satisfy your requirements?

Comment: @timgeb I wrote this exact function but it's buggy. I don't know why. If I run:     `for i in range(100):
        print ('True ', log_file._read_next(True))
        print ('False ', log_file._read_next(False))` the results are not expected

Comment: @Billie Without an MCVE that's impossible to debug, the problem might as well be in some other part. Sorry.

Comment: What is an MCVE?

Comment: @Billie a [MCVE]

Comment: @timgeb https://pastebin.com/J33uzChT Here is my code.. can you see any errors? If I iterate only with True parameter, I seems alright.

Comment: @Billie sorry, that's not a MCVE. You need to craft one and open a new question if you don't want to be a help vampire.

Comment: @timgeb I should have read the file with 'rb' access instead of 'r'. solved. thank you very much for the help

Comment: @Billie no problem! Glad the issue was resolved in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
from io import StringIO
s = StringIO('read me out')
s.read(5)
# → 'read '
savedpos = s.tell()
s.read(2)
# → 'me'
s.seek(savedpos)
```

to save the current position at any time and restore it later as needed.

To be explicit on `seek()`, in binary mode of the unterlying file stream, all values within the definition range are allowed, while in text mode, only 0 and any value returned from a previous `tell()` call are allowed.

Comment: @usr2564301 Is that also important if I use `tell()` to get that position? I'll have to try that naxt week at work, don't have Windows here…

Comment: @usr2564301 This is interesting. Probably, this is because seeking into a CRLF in text mode might be undesirable. Thus, I would consider the following invalid as well: `pos1 = f.tell(); f.write("x"); pos2 = f.tell(); f.seek(pos1); f.write("\n"); f.seek(pos2)` –  if we do that in Windows in Text mode, we are in the middle of a CRLF sequence.